# Splitting an XCode project into a library and app parts

Tags: xcode, xcode4

Back when I was using XCode 3 (quite a while back), I had multiple apps which share a common base code (common libraries, graphics utilities, common logos etc) in a single XCode project.

To create a new app, I would create a new target (copy off an existing app), deselect all the code/assets specific to that existing app, and add new files to the new app.

However, this is quite a chore to do in XCode 4 since you can't select a folder and do that anymore.

How does one solve this issue? Is it through using workspaces, or will this involve making the common codebase into a library? Can libraries include assets?